# What are the properties of a ring that still apply to its quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

For the time being I only know about integral domains, UFD, PID, Euclidian domains and Fields.

If a ring is one of the above structures, are its quotients by non-prime ideals also ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: No. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, but $\mathbb{Z}/4$ is not. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD, but $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a domain is *only* preserved by a quotient if the ideal you are quotienting by is prime.

Being a principal ideal **ring** is preserved by quotients, but as we just said the quotient need not be a domain.

In a field, there are no non-prime ideals, so that one doesn't fit in well.

You should run into more properties preserved in quotients soon. To name a few: [Artinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring), [Noetherian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring), [von Neumann regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring).